# How to read Kubernetes Service "random" value assigned to nodePort port inside container app?

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I have a containerized app that use Apache Ignite thick client. This uses bi directional communication with the Ignite cluster outside of Kubernetes. When it connects to Ignite it advertises it's I.P and port to Ignite. Ignite connects back to thick client for discovery/stats and other management tasks.

Obviously using default configs and deployment, the container will advertise its internal info.

In my previous container env `DC/OS` I was able to read the host i.p and the external random ports ("random" nodePort ports of node port in Kubernetes) as environment variables and Ignite cluster was able to connect trough the publicly advertised i.p and ports. And if the app was moved redeployed on another node it would just get the new host and new random port and Ignite would just reconnect back with the new info.

The host i.p I was able to solve with:

```
env:
- name: HOST_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

I was hopping that the Service Node Port would expose the target port but the environment variables available are still only the internal ones.

Service env vars I get:

```
MY_SERVICE_PORT_18080_TCP_PORT: 123456
MY_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT: 123456
```

With Kubectl I get:

```
kubectl get svc my-service

my-service   NodePort   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   <none>        123456:30086/TCP   2m46s
```

So is there's someway to get that `30086` port known to the container app?

One way I tell my self to quick fix this is to hardcode the targetPort in the service definition and hardcode the same port in the apps config. But this only works if you have 2-3 apps connecting to Ignite, let alone having to track which ports you have reserved for that purpose.

-- Update meant to say the random nodePort that is assigned by a service

Comment: Why not use the cluster internal dns name/port of the service?

Comment: Because Apache Ignite is running external to Kubernetes, I though that was clear with `This uses bi directional communication with the Ignite cluster outside of Kubernetes.`

Comment: @Chris I meant to say I would like to be able to read the random nodePort that is created by the node port service.

Comment: I still don't get why you'd need the nodeport from within the pod. There is no automatic way I know about to get that info. You could have an init container that reads the service spec an writes it into a file in a shared volume.

Comment: In Ignite, each client/server is aware and connects to one another, by sharing their info to each other. The client connects to EXTERNAL Ignite cluster from Kubernetes. The cluster connects back to the client. Since the client is not exposed, I tried nodePorts to expose the client. Since nodePorts are random the server doesn't know how to connect back. Using config the client can tell the server the proper external port. In DC/OS this was easy, external ports where available as env vars. Kube Service makes env vars available but only the ones we already know not the external exposed ports.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I'd suggest using an init container that loads the NodePort `kubectl get svc nginx-cluster-f5 -o json | jq -r '.spec.ports[0].nodePort' > /some/shared/volume` and have the main application read that information (or have the main container load it into env on startup).

Comment: Yeah, I had found another post about it. Was hoping it would be cleaner than that but ok. Since Service exposes the internal ports as env vars it would have been nice to get the external mapped ports as well.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris pointed out, init containers is the only way to do this... Though it would have been nice for Service Api to expose it as env var.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: private
          image: foo/bar
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-data
              mountPath: /config
          ports:
            - containerPort: 18080
          env:
      initContainers:
        - name: config-data
          image: curlimages/curl
          command: ["sh", "-c", "TOKEN=`cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`; curl -k -H \"Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN\" https://kubernetes.default:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/my-app >> /config/service.json"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-data
              mountPath: /config
      volumes:
        - name: config-data
          emptyDir: {}
```

For the init container I used `curlimages/curl` image as the container to provide the curl command.

In the command section above make sure to replace `default` if using another namespace and `my-app` with the name of your app obviously. Also for my purposes I chose to just write the full Json output to file. Since my app already parses json configs and has a json libs as dependency and I can read the Json as is.

You also need to give "view" access to the `default` service account or the service account that you may be using so it can call the curl api inside the init container.

```
kubectl create rolebinding default-view \
  --clusterrole=view \
  --serviceaccount=default:default \
  --namespace=default
```